# Pass Parameters to a JavaScript Function in button onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net

**ASPX File**

```
 <button runat="server" id="btnBookingStatus" class="clsBKStatus" type="button" onClick="return refreshStatus('My Parameter List')">Refresh Booking Status</button>
```

**JavaScript File**

```
function fnRefreshSatus(strMinNo, strSeqNo) {
    // Some code here  
}
```

I want to pass strMinNo, strSeqNo parameters from ASPX onClick event. How Can I pass these parameters to refreshStatus('My Parameter List') function?

Please help me on this

Comment: Put those values in a TextBox or HiddenField with javascript and read them in code behind.

Comment: you can put them as [`data-attributes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) on the button element and read them when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I need to pass these parameters from the values in text fields. For example, I have three text fields naming txtMinNo, txtSeqNo, txtUserId. I want to pass the values of these fields to the onClick even function and then to the JS function